# prisma: How to generate Custom id instead of 'ckasdasdw'?

Tags: javascript, database, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Currently, the Prisma database giving us every user's id starts with CK..... I need to change that. Is there any way to customize this?

as It is auto generated by prisma, how to approach to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: i have de same question you can solved this problem? any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and generate a unique id when you create the record.

for example

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';


const uuid  = uuidv4(); 

  prisma.user.create({
    id : uuid
     name : name
  });
```